# How to access the root objects of my ViewModel from within an EditorFor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel, editorfor

I have a view, and naturally, its own ViewModel:

```
@model TransportViewModel
```

I'm using an EditorFor to show a property list of one of my ViewModel Objects:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Car.WheelPropertyList)
```

Inside my EditorFor I can easily show my properties:

```
@model WheelProperty
@Html.Label(Model.PropertyA)
@Html.Label(Model.PropertyB)
```

My question is: How can I access the "root" of my ViewModel from within the EditorFor? The code written above is accessing:

> TransportViewModel.Car.WheelPropertyList.ElementAt(n).PropertyA
>   TransportViewModel.Car.WheelPropertyList.ElementAt(n).PropertyB

This is understood. The question is, how can I access, for instance:

> TransportViewModel.Train.ModelList.ElementAt(0).Name

From within my EditorFor?

I know it is possible to solve this issue using the ViewBag. However, I've always heard that if your ViewModel is perfect, you'll never need to use any ViewBag at all. Is this true or should I really use a ViewBag in this particular case?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, thanks, but how can that help you? Let's say that my model (viewmodel) is composed by the entity Car and the entity Train.

Comment: i have posted answer hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to provide a reference to the root object in the child object:

```
public class TransportViewModel  
{
    public List<WheelProperty> WheelPropertyList {get;set;}
    ...
}

public class WheelProperty
{
    public TransportViewModel TransportView {get;set;}
    public string PropertyA {get;set;}
    public string PropertyB {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

Then your Editor can easily reference the properties of the root object.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this to access the properties of Car:

```
foreach(var item in Model.Car.WheelPropertyList)
{
<span>@item.PropertyA</span>
<span>@item.PropertyB</span>
}
```

Comment: I know it, but that's not the point, I really need to use an EditorFor. My project binding depends on editorfors. My question is indeed: **How to access the root of the ViewModel from within the EditorFor**

Comment: you want to do it with Editor For?

Comment: Yes, I want to access Model.Train from inside an EditorFor that is doing "its stuff" on Model.Car.WheelPropertyList. Ohh... and I want to do it without ViewBags

Comment: You have to create navigation property like taylor answered